# Fetching NSManagedObjects based on attributes in related objects with inheritance?

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

I have a fairly complex CoreData data model with entities inheriting from others and I'm getting an exception when executing a predicate. For example:

```
    @"player.score > 1000";
```

Where:

```
    Player (abstract)
        - name
        - tags -> Tag

    LocalPlayer : Player
        - score
        - lives

    VirtualPlayer : Player
        - difficultyLevel


    Tag : NSManagedObject
        - name
        - color
        - player -> Player
```

I understand why, Tag has a relationship to Player, and score is an attribute on LocalPlayer, so it isn't valid since it isn't on other Player subclasses.  But I really don't want lose the hierarchy of my data model.

Is there a way (subqueries, maybe?) to limit my predicate to only run against LocalPlayer objects in the Tag:player->Player releationship?  Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are attempting to perform a fetch request using this predicate, it is not possible. The predicate is compiled to an SQL statement, and it is validated before sending to the backing database for execution. Interestingly, Core Data implements inheritance in a single, large table. So the SQL statement would actually not fail and return a correct result. But it is failed before execution by the Core Data predicate parser, which validates it against its model. To overcome this, consider promoting the `score` property to the abstract class `Player`. Perhaps, store it as an `NSNumber`, which would allow having a `nil` value to indicate irrelevance (in cases of `VirtualPlayer` objects).

You could also reverse your fetch request, fetching all local players with score of 1000, and then taking a list of all the tags:

```
NSSet* tags = [[moc executeFetchRequest:localPlayersRequest error:NULL] valueForKey:@"@distinctUnionOfSets.tags"];
```

Note however, that this is less optimal, and you may consider prefetching the `tags` relationship for quicker union of sets.

Comment: Thanks Leo, moving the attribute down seems like the simplest solution, I just wanted to avoid it to keep the classes cleaner where possible.

Comment: I considered reversing the fetch as you suggested, but I wanted to take advantage of the fetched results controller and reversing the fetch would remove the benefits that it provides by tracking changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have a predicate like this. From a conceptional standpoint, a `Player` is not guaranteed to have a `score`. Instead, you should set the entity of your request to `LocalPlayer`.

Even better, in my opinion, would be to avoid the inheritance complexity altogether. If the attributes list in your question is exhaustive, I would think that you had better simplify the model to just a `Player` entity to include all the attributes. You could even add a boolean `isVirtual` to make query filters easier.

Keep it simple and readable. You may "lose the hierarchy" but you will "gain simplicity".

Comment: This isn't a valid solution because VirtualPlayers can be tagged too. I appreciate the reply, but this would actually make things more complex and would unnecessarily clutter the base class.